# Mock API calls made in Application class as part of UI testing

Tags: android, mocking, android-espresso, android-testing, mockwebserver

**Background:**

Our Android Application, onCreate, launches some initialisation use cases that execute some network API calls.

In parallel, our LAUNCHER Activity is launched.

In our UI Tests, we use MockWebServer to stub API responses and we use ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR 1.1.1

**Problem:**

In our UI tests involving the Main Activity, we would like to stub different responses for the initialisation API calls, from the test.

In other words, each test should be able to specify what responses the initialisation API calls return.

However, since the initialisation services launch before the Activity, and all the code in the UI tests run AFTER the application is already launched. We are no able to influence the responses that occur before it.

**Question:**

Is there a way to manually launch the application from within a Test like we can do with an ActivityTestRule for an Activity? This will allow us to stub the initialisation API calls based on the requirements of the test and then launch the application.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the `ActivityTestRule` docs:

```
ActivityTestRule (Class<T> activityClass, 
                boolean initialTouchMode, 
                boolean launchActivity)
```

So you can set to `false` the `launchActivity` parameter:

```
@Rule
public final ActivityTestRule<ActivityToTest> mActivityRule = 
    new ActivityTestRule<>(ActivityToTest.class, true, false);
```

and perform the things you need at the beginning of the tests and then launch the activity at the moment you want with null as a parameter:

```
mActivity = mActivityRule.launchActivity(null);
```

or with an intent with the needed extras in case you need them:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("your_key", "your_value");
mActivity = mActivityRule.launchActivity(intent);
```

Comment: even if launchActivity is false, the application class is instantiated nonetheless